# SQL Like statement with variable in python

Tags: python, sql, database

Here is part of the code:

```
import sqlite3
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import Tk, Label,Button,Toplevel,Entry

def display():
    m,n=0,0
    c=str(en.get())
    print(c)
    t=Toplevel()
    d="%"+c+"%"
    cursor = conn.execute("""SELECT * from (select * from
        user_1 union all SELECT *
        from user_3 union all SELECT *
        from user_4 union all SELECT *
        from user_5 union all SELECT *
        from user_2 ) where id like %s""",(d,))
    for row in cursor: 
        print("ID = ", row[0])
        print("IMG = ",row[1])

    t.mainloop()
    print("Operation done successfully");
    conn.close()

w=Tk()
w.title("gui")
en=Entry(w)
en.grid(row=0)
conn = sqlite3.connect('datastorage.db')
print("Opened database successfully");
a=Button(w,text="display",command=display).grid()
```

The sql LIKE statement is generating a syntax error as follows:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ABC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\Python tut\trial.py", line 18, in display
    from user_2 ) where id like %s""",(d,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

c is the string input by the user, it's value is stored in d as I want all strings containing the string c.
I know there are many similar questions but none seem to solve my problem. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Why do you have several user_1, user_2 etc tables?

Comment: @jarlh That is irrelevant to the question

Comment: @jarlh I have a database from which I am extracting images in the above code. That database has those 5 tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
c = str(en.get())
sql = f"""SELECT * from (select * from
        user_1 union all SELECT *
        from user_3 union all SELECT *
        from user_4 union all SELECT *
        from user_5 union all SELECT *
        from user_2 ) where id like '%{c}%'"""
cursor = conn.execute(sql)
```

Comment: I'll do that as soon as it lets me, there is a timer